# Regex for full name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ascii, utf

I am trying to figure out a regex for full name that matches the following conditions:

1. no number or symbol within this range: `!@#\$%\^&*+_=`

if it is an English-like name, then:

1. First letter of each word is capital.
2. There is at least one space
3. It can't be all capital in one word. i.e. `John McDoe` can pass, `John MCDOE` can't.

else (other languages like Shina, Korean, Jap), all pass.

```
Should Pass:

Ms. Jan Levinson-Gould         
Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr.    
Brett D'Arras-d'Haudracey      
Brüno                          
John Doe
John McDoe                       
Mary-Jo Jane Sally Smith
阿阿阿
阿阿 阿阿


Should Fail:

Fatty Mc.Error$                
FA!L                           
#arold Newm@n                  
N4m3 w1th Numb3r5
john doe
JOHN DOE
John MCDOE
```

---

UPDATE

I know we can't get it 100% right. But I am trying to learn from [Quora's](https://www.quora.com/) real full name system. They freak out some people who have put in ridiculous names and increase the likelihood of people giving the real full name at the second time.

Comment: [A *must* read article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Is this down voted because its unsolvable?

Comment: I don't know, maybe because you didn't show what you've tried ? I don't want to say "unsolvable", but the range you specified doesn't make sense `[^\`!@#$%^&*+_=\d]`, I mean there are way more UTF-8 symbols that shouldn't be in a name according to your logic. Have you ever thought about names like [Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law_in_Sweden#Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116) ? That's just one example...

Comment: thanks for pointing out the misleading sentence. I have rephrased it. So far I am using `/^[^0-9\`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]+$/`. And I have explained my aim in update. Thanks

Comment: What is `unreasonably capitalised`? Or, more exact, should a name like `John McDoe` pass or fail?

Comment: @Arjan You are right. My description was very thoughtless. The way Quora does it is they don't allow all capital letters in one word. So `John McDoe` will pass `John MCDOE` won't pass. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps, will match any number of words:

```
string.split(/ +/).detect{|s| not (s[0].upcase == s[0] && s[1..-1].downcase == s[1..-1]) }
```

This solution depends on `String#upcase` and `String#downcase` to be able to do their stuff with international characters.

On second thought, any solution to this problem will have real-world drawbacks that are result of funny user input

EDIT, lol upvote @HamZa for http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: But will this allow languages other than English, e.g. French, German, Chinese. And more than 1 space?

Comment: Ah, this will support multiple spaces, but not non-ascii characters, plan B would be using ruby to detect, not regexp, let me update the answer

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into Ruby method instead of purely regex now.